# Creating tableView inside tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexpath

I've created a tableView with prototype cells. Inside each of these prototype cells is another tableView with different prototype cells. I've linked this all together fine, but I'm having trouble modifying the innermost prototype cells. Here is why.
Here is the relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "outerCell") as! outerCell
//would obviously make some modification to cell here, like cell.title = "test" or something
            let cell2 = cell.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "innerCell") as! innerCell
            cell2.commentText.text = "sus"

        //NEED TO DIFFERENTIATE HERE ON HOW TO KNOW WHICH CELL TO RETURN
//e.g. NEED TO RETURN either cell1 or cell2, depending on the tableView

    }
```

My code for outerCell looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class outerCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        commentTableView.delegate = self
        commentTableView.dataSource = self

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "innerCell", for: indexPath) as! commentCell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


}
```

See, the main problem is, both these table views work fine and all, but, in the first chunk of code, if I just do something like,

```
if tableView == self.tableView{
    return cell }
else ...
```

this won't work, as tableView always seems to be self.tableView.

How can I modify my code so that I can actually impact the text displayed in the inner cell, and the outer cell, in the same block of code?

Also, please note, I know that, based on the example given here, there is no need for these nested cells. I've just simplified the code here to focus on what's important - my actual code has a lot of stuff happening in both the inner and outer cell.

Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need the `dataSource` (and probably `delegate` in your case) of the `outerCell` to be set to your `ViewController` instance.

Comment: ah okay, how can I do this?

Comment: e.g. what do I write instead of tableView.delegate = self

Comment: I'm not positive this will work, but in `func tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)->UITableViewCell` below where your `let cell = ...` line, set `cell.dataSource = self` and `cell.delegate = self`.

Comment: "I've created a tableView with prototype cells. Inside each of these prototype cells is another tableView with different prototype cells. "  If you have two table view objects, why do you only have one IBOutlet-connected tableView object, then?

Comment: @ElTomato okay how do I fix this then

Comment: What is the purpose of nesting table views?

Answer (score 1):

you need to first create two different cell classes.
In outer class :

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SearchPreferredJobTableViewCell
            cell.responseCreateBookingObj = { [unowned self] (returnObject) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    tableView.beginUpdates()
                    }
// do your logic

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
                        tableView.endUpdates()
                    } }

       return cell 
}
```

// other cell class
Declare variable

```
var responseCreateBookingObj : APIServiceSuccessCallback?
```

// send callback from you want to send

```
guard let callBack = self.responseCreateBookingObj else{
        return
    }
    callBack(true as AnyObject)
```

// also do in when user scroll it'll manage

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    tableView.beginUpdates()
                    }
```

// do your logic

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
                    tableView.endUpdates()
                }
```

}

Comment: hmm, there is no type "SearchPreferredJobTableViewCell" as far as I can see

Comment: this is just another cell class that you'll  create for inside the tble view cell.